# How to throw a ball into a cup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, physics, game-physics

I have an image of a ball, a cup, and an inner and outer div that represent a throw power bar.
When the user clicks the ball, the power bar starts to increment and then decrements. When the user clicks the ball a 2nd time, the throw power bar stops and the ball is thrown.

As I have began coding this, I realized certain things are going to be extremely complicated, even though the idea itself is rather simple.

For example, I want the ball to be able to "bounce", meaning I will need to not only keep track of the balls x and y coordinates, but also a z coordinate representing depth.

When the ball falls to bounce, the z coordinate with be decremented, and the image of the ball should be scaled down in size, and when it begins bouncing back up, it should scale up in size, again based on the z coordinate.  I also want the ball to bounce off the cup if the z coordinate is below a certain value by the time it reaches the cup, go into the cup if it is a certain sweet spot, or go over the cup if it's z value is over that sweet spot.

In the interest of keeping this somewhere short, I'll just post what I have so far.  This example is lacking certain things that I was hoping people here could help me with.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Lsh78nw/

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        #ball {
            position:absolute;
            width:75px;
            height:75px;
        }

        #cup1 {
            position:absolute;
            left:375px;
        }

        #outerPowerMeter {
            position:absolute;
            width:25px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:red;
        }

        #innerPowerMeter {
            position:absolute;
            width:25px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:black;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
            var yPos = 500;
            var xPos = 400;
            var zPos = 100;
            var ballWidth = 75;
            var ballHeight = 75;
            var throwBallInterval;
            var changeBallSizeInterval;

            ball.style.top = yPos + "px";
            ball.style.left = xPos + "px";

            var cup1 = document.getElementById("cup1");

            var powerMeter = document.getElementById("innerPowerMeter");
            var powerMeterValue = 0;
            var powerMeterHeight = 100;
            var powerMeterActive = false;
            var powerMeterInterval;

            powerMeter.style.height = powerMeterHeight + "px";

            ball.onclick = function() {
                if (powerMeterActive == false) {
                    powerMeterActive = true;
                    startPowerMeter();
                } else {
                    powerMeterActive = false;
                    stopPowerMeter();
                    throwBall();
                }
            }

            function throwBall() {
                throwBallInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    yPos = yPos - 1;
                    ball.style.top = yPos + "px";
                }, 1);

                changeBallSizeInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    zPos = zPos - 1;
                    ballWidth = ballWidth - 1;
                    ballHeight = ballHeight - 1;
                    ball.style.width = ballWidth;
                    ball.style.height = ballHeight;
                }, 100);
            }

            function startPowerMeter() {
                var increment = true;
                powerMeterInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (increment == true) {
                        powerMeterValue = powerMeterValue + 1;
                        powerMeter.style.height = (powerMeterHeight - powerMeterValue) + "px";
                        if (powerMeterValue == 100) {
                            increment = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        powerMeterValue = powerMeterValue - 1;
                        powerMeter.style.height = (powerMeterHeight - powerMeterValue) + "px";
                        if (powerMeterValue == 0) {
                            increment = true;
                        }
                    }
                },1);
            }

            function stopPowerMeter() {
                clearInterval(powerMeterInterval);
            }

            function detectCollision() { }

            function detectGoal() { }
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="cup1" src="http://beerwar.com/game/images/cup.png">
        <img id="ball" src="http://beerwar.com/game/images/ball.png">
        <div id="outerPowerMeter">
            <div id="innerPowerMeter"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what are you actually asking? I've taken the liberty to remove a lot of the irrelevant information from your post, but I can't find a actual question in there. Is there something "not working" about this code? What's happening, and what do you expect / want to happen?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  I will copy and paste the "meat" of what I asked, and if that is still not straightforward, let me know.

For example, I want the ball to be able to "bounce", meaning I will need to not only keep track of the balls x and y coordinates, but also a z coordinate representing depth. When the ball falls to bounce, the z coordinate with be decremented, and the image of the ball should be scaled down in size, and when it begins bouncing back up, it should scale up in size, again based on the z coordinate.

Comment: I also want the ball to bounce off the cup if the z coordinate is below a certain value by the time it reaches the cup, go into the cup if it is a certain sweet spot, or go over the cup if it's z value is over that sweet spot.

Comment: Sure, I read that, but that's not a problem statement. That's just asking SO to write you some bouncing functions.

Comment: how do you think z-coordinate is mapped on 2d screen? - You can try to reduce size of your ball to give such illusion.

Comment: If I had to sum up what I'm asking, it would be how to make my ball bounce, how to detect collision with the cup if the z coordinate is to low, and how to calculate the path the ball will take when it collides with the cup.  The reason it's kind of hard to explain is because my question is actually pretty complex, but I'm trying.

Comment: Ravi, yeah I realize I can scale the ball depending on the z coordinate.  That is my plan.  When it falling because of the force of gravity, the ball will shrink, then grow after it hits the "ground", then shrink again, then grow again, ect ect.

Comment: Hopefully if you re-read my original comment, you can understand I am asking multiple questions.

1.  Make ball bounce, depending on throw power.  Higher throw power, no bounce.  Lower throw power, bounce.

2.  Detect collision with cup if z coordinate is too low by the time it reaches the cup.  If the z coordinate is in a certain range, it will go in.  If it's above that range, it will go over.

Comment: How about first trying to achieve this in 2D? (Throw a ball from left to right) There are plenty of tutorials out there to make a ball bounce like that. Then, instead of changing the ball's `y` coordinate, you modify it's size.

Comment: David, Stack Overflow is not a site where you can just ask for functionality. You're expected to show some research effort, or at least have some kind of attempt at bouncing, in this case. SO isn't here to write your code for you, but to help you fix broken code. For example, look at [this site](http://cssdeck.com/labs/lets-make-a-bouncing-ball-in-html5-canvas) (Specifically the `update()` function), to get an idea of how to make things bounce.

Comment: I think I understand what you are suggesting Cerbrus.  And technically what I am trying to do isn't true 3d.  Kind of like 2 and a half D :)  Anyways I'm probably not going to get exactly what I'm asking for, I guess i'll blame myself, but in my own defense it's a bit tough to explain.  I tried, and got downvoted, haha.

Comment: That's fine, you are making alot of assumptions.  I am just trying to learn from others through open dialog, I'm sorry if this isn't the place to do it.  I'm not even asking anyone to write a single line of code, just pointing me in the right direction is more than enough.  Thanks for the example atleast, I suppose.  I am more than capable of figuring this out on my own without SO, but it's going to take 10x longer and I am a practical person, as in I like to save time.

Comment: And figuring out how to make the ball bounce is only a small portion of what I asked.  Not only do I want to it bounce, but also detect collision with the cup, calculate the path the ball takes when the collision occurs, detect a "goal", and a few other things that are harder than they sound for a noob.  But oh well, i'll figure it all out the hard way, through tons of trial and error I suppose.

Comment: And lastly, in reference to your last comment, I read this page in the help section.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

In my opinion, these question are allowable.  I am sorry you didn't understand what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you posted such a detailed case, i thought i give you some pointers. Mind you: this is mostly vector math. I'm not a physicist either, but vector math isn't that complicated luckily! Some pythagoras here and there and you are set.

A good an fast library for that is [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/)

A couple of things to get you going. *Please note: it is pseudo code, but it does explain the concept of it.*

- Keep a vector for the position of the ball
- Keep a vector for the position of the cup (where the ball should hit)
- Keep a vector for the position of 'the camera' (since you want to scale the ball based on distance from the camera. Doesn't have to be accurate, just get the idea across)
- Keep a vector for the 'direction of the force' you are going to apply to the ball. (this can be multiplied with the force from your force meter)
- Keep a vector for the 'velocity of the ball'
- Keep a vector for the 'gravity'

Your 'throw' function would become something along the lines of:

```
ball.velocity = throw.direction * throw.power
setInterval(tick,50);
```

Basicly, your 'tick' function (the function you apply every x-time)

```
ball.velocity += gravity; // we apply gravity to the speed of the ball. Pulling it down
ball.position = ball.position + ball.velocity // we add the velocity to the position every tick

if (ball.position.y < ball.radius) // if the ball is below its radius, it is colliding with the ground
{
    ball.position.y = 0 - ball.position.y; // just invert its 'up' position, to make it not collide with the ground anymore
    // to make the ball go back up again, invert its 'up' velocity. Gravity will get it down eventually
    // dampening applied so it will bounce up less every time. For instance make that 0.9.
    ball.velocity.y = 0 - (ball.velocity.y * dampening);
}
// the scale of the ball is not determined by its height, but by its distance from the camera
distanceFromCamera = (camera.position - ball.position).length()
ball.scale = 100 - (distanceFromCamera / scaleFactor);

// to make a simply guess if we are hitting the target, just check the distance to it.
distanceFromTarget = (cup.target.position - ball.position).length()
if (distanceFromTarget <= cup.target.radius) // if we 'hit the target'
    handleHit()
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  I really appreciate you taking the time to write it.  Thanks!  I will be referencing it frequently during this project/learning experience, so it wasn't wasted.  :D

Comment: Not a problem :-) To make it all easier to grasp, build it in 2d first. The math will be exactly the same but it's easier to visualise. Just shoot me a message here if you're stuck.

Comment: Awesome.  I will message you for sure, but only if necessary.  Regardless I'll be sure to give you a shout out in my games credits when I have a finished product.  Am trying to make a Beer Pong game for Facebook and mobile btw, really popular game amongst college kids :D